# How to draw any PNG format in Core Graphics

Tags: ios, png, core-graphics

We have code that creates a CGImage from a PNG data provider, and then draws it on a CGBitmapContext. Most PNGs work fine, but some PNG formats are not supported (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB)), so we get a NULL context. This is how we create it:

`CGContextRef imageContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image), 0, CGImageGetColorSpace(image), CGImageGetBitmapInfo(image));`

Now, while this way doesn't work in Core Graphics, making a UIImage with the same PNG works. And we did confirm manually that the given PNG format is indeed not supported (24 bpp, 8 bpc, RGB only (no alpha channel)). Furthermore, passing a CGBitmapInfo of kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst works!

So, it seems that there is a way to make stray PNGs render anyway, and UIImage implements this. But we really can't use UIImage here (we want to pre-render the bitmap on a background thread), hence the question - what is a good heuristic to render all PNGs in Core Graphics? Alternatively, what other drawing techniques can we use to achieve the same effect (but without using Core Graphics)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:** `UIImage` is thread safe, nowadays. [From the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> It also means that image objects are themselves safe to use from any
>   thread.

**Second:** Your problem is only in the restricted amount of available CGBitmapContext pixel formats.

If you always use 32bpp, RGB with premultiplied alpha everything should work. Of course you would not get the PNG's original pixel format (like color palettes, B&W or whatever) but that usually does not matter since drawing the image on screen is done in RGB.

Comment: Re second: if you mean serving only a specific format, that's a last-resort solution. And it feels like we don't have to go there quite yet. Re first: that's interesting, I'm trying to implement pre-rendering using UIKit, but at least [UIImage drawAtPoint:] doesn't behave as I expected it to. I'll keep trying, but the CG solution has already proven itself.

Comment: @VladimirGritsenko What I meant with the second proposal is: Always use a full RGBA, 32bpp CGBitmapContext. Then you would be able to render every PNG (that ImageIO understands) into this context. ImageIO is the underlying library used by UIImage and CGImage to read images. It can read every PNG I stumbled upon. The problems you did encounter were due to the fact that you tried to set up the image context with the pixel format of the PNG. This does not work as CGBitmapContext is quite restricted regarding supported formats.

Comment: Here's [the list of supported bitmap formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB), by the way.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe, I just had the biggest facepalm moment I've had in a while. I did try to make the context the same as the PNG, which is indeed completely unnecessary. Thanks! :-)